# Timber Wordpress display post in each category

Tags: wordpress, twig, timber

I use Timber plugin with Wordpress. I would like to create a loop which display 4 articles in each category.

**publications.php**

```
$context = Timber::get_context();
$post = new TimberPost();

$cat_id = wp_get_post_categories($post->ID);
$context['each_cat'] = Timber::get_posts(array('cat' => $cat_id[0], 'posts_per_page' => 4));

Timber::render( array( 'publications.twig', 'page.twig' ), $context );
```

**publications.twig**

```
{% for category in each_cat %}
<h2 class="title">{{category.name}}</h2>
    <article class="article--box">
        {% include "bloc_preview.twig" %}
    </article>
{% endfor %}
```

The include `bloc_preview.twig` is a preview of each post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, @jandon thanks for asking these on StackOverflow (instead of clouding-up the GitHub issues with support Qs). The easiest way to accomplish what you're looking for is to use the [`.posts` method on your term objects](http://timber.github.io/timber/#posts). Based on your example, you can do this all in Twig...

**publications.twig**

```
<h2>{{ post.title }}</h2>
<h3>Related Posts</h3>
{% for term in post.terms('category') %}
    <h3>Related Posts in {{ term.name }}</h3>
    <ul>
        {% for child_post in term.posts(4) %}
        <li><a href="{{ child_post.link }}">{{ child_post.title }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you. Nothing is display. I don't know why

Answer (score 1):

Might be a typo it works with:

```
{% for child_post in term.posts %}
```

instead of:

```
{% for child_post in terms.posts %}
```